# properties cannot be accessed in error handler

Tags: dart, bwu-datagrid

Two questions:

Looking at the highlighted line in https://github.com/bwu-dart/bwu_datagrid/blob/master/example/src/composite_editor_item_details/app_element.dart#L120

1) why does the line

```dart
var idx = e.validationResults.errors.length;
```

always throws an error?

Exception: Uncaught Error: The null object does not have a getter 'length'.

```dart
NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'length'
Receiver: null
Arguments: []
Stack Trace:
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:45)
#1      validationErrorHandler (http://localhost:8080/epimss_design.html.12.dart:184:42)
#2      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1020)
#3      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341)
#4      _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:270)
#5      _SyncBroadcastStreamController._sendData (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:346)
#6      _BroadcastStreamController.add (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:237)
#7      EventBus.fire (package:bwu_datagrid/core/event_bus.dart:61:19)
#8      _commitCurrentEdit (package:bwu_datagrid/bwu_datagrid.dart:3626:25)
#9      EditorLock.commitCurrentEdit (package:bwu_datagrid/core/range.dart:235:82)
#10     BwuDatagrid._commitEditAndSetFocus (package:bwu_datagrid/bwu_datagrid.dart:3045:40)
#11     _handleKeyDown (package:bwu_datagrid/bwu_datagrid.dart:2632:39)
```

The same thing happens for other properties as well such as field and column etc.

2) How can I test that the validationResult returns true? The error handler seems to only fires when there is an ValidationError.

My validator is shown below

```dart
 import 'package:bwu_datagrid/datagrid/helpers.dart' show Column, GridOptions,
    MapDataItem, MapDataItemProvider;
  import 'package:bwu_datagrid/bwu_datagrid.dart' show BwuDatagrid;
  import 'package:bwu_datagrid/formatters/formatters.dart' show CheckmarkFormatter;
  import 'package:bwu_datagrid/editors/editors.dart' show CheckboxEditor, EditorArgs,
    IntegerEditor, TextEditor;
  import 'package:bwu_datagrid/core/core.dart' show AddNewRow, ActiveCellChanged,
    ItemBase, ValidationError;
  import 'package:bwu_datagrid/plugins/row_selection_model.dart' show RowSelectionModel;

  import 'package:epimss_podo/reg.dart' show Email, EMAIL_FORM_EVENT;
  import 'package:epimss_shared/shared.dart' show toggleCoreCollapse, onBwuCellChangeHandler;
  import 'package:epimss_shared/validators.dart' show BwuRequiredEmailValidator,
    BwuRequiredNounValidator;
```

Custom validators:

```dart
const String REQUIRED_EMAIL_REGEX = r"\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b";
const String REQUIRED_NOUN_REGEX = r"\b[a-z'-]{2,}\b";

final RegExp _requiredNounValidator = new RegExp( REQUIRED_NOUN_REGEX, caseSensitive: false );
bool isRequiredNounValid( String property ) =>
    _requiredNounValidator.hasMatch( property );

final RegExp _requiredEmailPropertyValidator = new RegExp( REQUIRED_EMAIL_REGEX, caseSensitive: false );
bool isRequiredEmailPropertyValid( String property ) => _requiredEmailPropertyValidator.hasMatch( property );


class BwuRequiredEmailValidator extends bwu.Validator {
  bwu.ValidationResult call( dynamic value ) {
    if ( isRequiredEmailPropertyValid( value ) ) {
      return new bwu.ValidationResult( true );
    } else {
      return new bwu.ValidationResult( false, 'Valid email address required.' );
    }
  }
}


class BwuRequiredNounValidator extends bwu.Validator {
  bwu.ValidationResult call( dynamic value ) {
    if ( isRequiredNounValid( value) ) {
      return new bwu.ValidationResult( true );
    } else {
      return new bwu.ValidationResult( false, 'Valid noun is required.' );
    }
  }
}
```

Validation error handler:

```dart
void validationErrorHandler( ValidationError e ) {
  //print ( e.validationResults.errors.length );
  print ( e.column.field );

  if ( e.validationResults.isValid )
    print( 'retVal is true' );
  else
    print( 'retVal is false' );

  errorMsg = e.validationResults.message;
  var editor = e.editor;
  print ( 'valResult valid |' + e.validationResults.isValid.toString() );

  var result = e.validationResults;

  if ( e.validationResults.isValid ) {
    errorMsg = 'EMAIL';
  } else {
    errorMsg = result.message;
  }

  print( editor.runtimeType ); // aslways print TextEditor

  if ( editor != null ) {
    //var colId = editor.column.id;
    if ( editor is TypeEditor ) {
      email.isTypeValid = true;
    }

    if ( editor is AddressEditor ) {
      email.isAddressValid = false;
    }

    //print( encode ( email ) );
  }
}
```

Comment: How does your validator look like?

Comment: Please see validationErrorHandler( ValidationError e ) above.

Comment: I assume you are using a custom validator. Can you add the code of the  Validator class please.

Answer (score 0):

You get the exception because the field `e.validationResults.errors` is null.
You can't access the `length` property of `null` thus the exception is thrown.
The field `errors` is null because in this call

```dart
return new bwu.ValidationResult( false, 'Valid email address required.' );
```

you didn't pass a value for the optional `errors` parameter

```dart
class ValidationResult {
  bool isValid = false;
  String message;
  List<ValidationErrorSource> errors;

  ValidationResult(this.isValid, [this.message, this.errors]);
}
```

#### Hint:

As far as I know breakpoints don't work for code within `<script>` tags (I saw this in the example code I got in an email).
I therefore advise to move your code from the `email_form.html` file to a `email_form.dart` file.
Then you can use the debugger and investigate the values at runtime which also helps a lot to learn what others peoples code is actually doing.

[image]

#### Fire custom event  from Editor

```dart
class AddressEditor extends bwu.TextEditor {

static const VALIDATION_SUCCEEDED = const EventType<ValidationError>(
      'custom-validation-succeeded');
  ...

@override
bwu.ValidationResult validate() {
  var result = super.validate();

  args.grid.eventBus.fire(AddressEditor.VALIDATION_SUCCEEDED, new ValidationError(this,
    editor: this,
    cellNode: args.grid.getActiveCellNode(),
    validationResults: result,
    cell: args.grid.getActiveCell(),
    column: column));
  return result;
}
```

// you can register the same handler as for the validation error event
grid.eventBus.onEvent(AddressEditor.VALIDATION_SUCCEEDED).listen(validationErrorHandler);

I have not tried this code but it should work.

Comment: I was using the docs at http://bwu-dart.github.io/bwu_datagrid/dartdoc/#bwu_datagrid/bwu_datagrid-libraries.ValidationResult. It gave no indication of such an option. Now looking in the packages I see what you are saying. Thanks for the hint. I only wish the IDE Editor had the ability to display two editor pages side by side so I could work on both the .html and .dart simultaneously. I dislike going too and fro between both editors. I know eclipse IDE had a plugin that accomplish that task. I wonder if the dart editor team would consider same.

Comment: You can do this in DartEditor. Just drag a tab by it's caption and move it to the right border of the edit area. A line indicates where the tab will be positioned when you drop it. You can then move other tabs from one side to the other by just drag-n-dropping them over other tabs. You can split the editor area to more than two sections (see screenshot above with 4 files side by side). I also rather jump to the source (Ctrl+click) and read comments there than using the API docs. In the source I can see doc comments and code at one place.

Comment: Thanks. Always wanted it but never tried the splitting!

Comment: In my validationErrorHandler above, the statement | if ( e.validationResults.isValid ) | always prints false. It seems as if the error handler is triggered only when an error exist. This is logical, but why then would | return new bwu.ValidationResult( true ); | How can I access the return value of the last statement in this comment.

Comment: The event you use to register the handler is `grid.onBwuValidationError.listen(validationErrorHandler)` thus only fired on validation error not on validation success. I'll have a look if there is another event that might be a better fit for your requirement.

Comment: I didn't find something that would allow you that. You return `new bwu.ValidationResult(true)` to tell the grid that the value is valid and can be applied to the data item. If you return false the grid doesn't store the value. Can you explain what you try to do, maybe there are alternative ways to accomplish it.

Comment: In all my models I have an isValid method on the each class. If all relevent properties are valid I set this value to true, otherwise it is set to false. I access this value to change the paper-icon-button icon to either a tick or warning icon to indicate the validation status of the contained UI. Hence the relevance of knowing when model property is valid and by extension the class isValid method.

Comment: The `onBwuCellChange` is only fired when the validation result is true. I think this is the only one you can use out of the box. An alternative solution is to fire a custom event from a custom Editor (like your AddressEditor) . BWU DataGrid calls `editor.validate()` which returns the `ValidationResult`. You can override `validate()` and after `super.validate()` fire your custom event. I'll add a bit of code to get you started to my answer.

Comment: The | args.grid.eventBus.fire(AddressEditor.VALIDATION_SUCCEEDED, result); | throws the following error | Breaking on exception: type 'ValidationResult' is not a subtype of type 'EventData' of 'data'. | The result is also flagged in the editor with |The argument type 'ValidationResult' cannot be assigned to the parameter type 'EventData'|. Looking in the EventData class, I see other events, but not ValidationResult. Thanks

Comment: You are right, I missed that. The `ValidationResult` needs to be wrapped in a `ValidationError`. I updated the code.